# Styling forms and django form values

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm trying to style a form with CSS. First of all I haven't seen a complete example, other than on the official documentation, so I would appreciate any blog entries, or articles.

Now on my form, a typical Charfield gets translated on html like this:

```
<input type="text" name="artists" id="id_artists" />
```

If my form contains errors on some field, the previous Charfield remembers the value and goes:

```
<input type="text" name="artists" value="Pink Floyd" id="id_artists"  />
```

How can I get this value (`value="Pink Floyd"`) in django forms? Say my field is `{{form.artists}}`, I can use `{{form.artists}}` as the field, `{{form.artists.label}}` as label, `{{form.artists.errors}}` and `{{form.artists.help_text}}`, but how about this value?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

Create the input field specifically, rather than relying on django to auto-create it.

Something like:

```
<input type="text" name="artists" id="id_artists" value="{{form.artists.title}}" />
```

should work

Comment: Hi Steerpike,

this will do the job, however I still need to get that value, in order to provide it when there are errors on some other field on the form - otherwise it gets blanked.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the current value of the field from the `data` property:

```
{{ form.artists.data }}
```

I can't see the Django documentation mentioning this, but it works...

Answer (score 0):

You can also add additional validation to the form class to do something with the form data.  From [djangobook.com](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter07/):

```
from django import forms

class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    subject = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = forms.EmailField(required=False)
    message = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)

    def clean_message(self):
        message = self.cleaned_data['message']
        num_words = len(message.split())
        if num_words < 4:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Not enough words!")
        return message
```

Inside of the `clean_message` method you can access a given field using the `self.cleaned_data` dictionary.  This dictionary is available for any form that is validated.

Be sure to return the field, in this case `message`, or else `None` is returned.